# Implementing java.util.List - looking for a JUnit test for validation

Tags: java, list, collections, junit

I'm implementing the `java.util.List` interface.

As I'm implementing it method by method I'm also writing test cases for them in `JUnit` 4.10.

I'm wondering, are there any already prepared tests that cover 100% of the functionality that a `List` provides?

Comment: Probably not...I don't think that normal devs would bother testing guarantees made by Sun/Oracle from their own API.  Given the API though, it wouldn't be hard to whip up a few tests for all of the implemented methods.

Comment: I would think that there are tests for this in the JDK. I don't know if those are included if you download the jdk sources, and I think the JDK devs don't use JUnit but something else.

Comment: Hm... maybe I should look up in Apache Collections or Guava and see if they have some tests in the source.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/test/java/util/Collection/MOAT.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I stumbled upon this blog post:  [Google Guava Collection Test Suite](http://www.gamlor.info/wordpress/2012/09/google-guava-collection-test-suite/)

*The Google Guava Testlib brings a whole test suite which tests the behavior of Set, List and Map implementations. You can specify which features your collections support and then profit from the hundreds of tests Google has written for you.*

So this is the real deal to be used when testing a custom implementation of a Collection interface.

Answer (score 2):

The OpenJDK is not tested with JUnit, but with their own tool jreg because when they started their regression testing, JUnit was not yet availble or did not provide sufficient features. After some googling, [this](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/test/java/util/Collection/MOAT.java) shows up, and apart from being a jreg test, it seems to be what you are looking for.

As for JUnit, I don't know if anyone has done it. Since JDK uses another tool, perhaps you could look what the folks behind Apache Harmony were using.

Comment: I always found this source: https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u/tree/master/test but the test directory has only a Makefile. https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/tree/master/test is what I was looking for, but for jdk8. What is the difference between these two repos? And where I find the origin repo, not just the github mirror?